# Where to upload layers in geoexplorer?

Tags: layers, geoexplorer, boundless-suite

I just install opengeo suite (boundless) in my machine and try to explore it. I followed the instruction in user manual and I encountered a problem. In "Load your data with GeoExplorer" part, after clicking the plus sign, I did not find the upload layers option like the **[user manual said](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/webmaps/easypublish/load.html)**.

The only option is "add layers", no "upload layers".

Can anyone help me and tell me what happens here?

Comment: Is GeoServer running on the local machine? You can check it manually or check if "Local GeoServer" is available as a layer source. If not it means GeoExplorer can't communicate with GeoServer on the same host and port it is on.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you're using OpenGeo Suite version 4.0.2. In 4.0.1 the upload option was temporarily removed.